# Fixing an old ntp server with no leap second

Tags: ntp

I have to take care of an old STRATUM1 (GPS source) ntp server. It is installed with Free BSD 8.0 and ntp-4.2.6p3 and has an uptime of 1800+ days. It is used to provide time to many other servers in the datacenter.

Comparing the accuracy of this server's time with other public ntp servers, this one is -1 second ahead. The ntp.conf has no leapfile reference so I think this server has not taken into account the leap seconds.

The question is, can it be fixed?. Is there a way to add the leap second know?. I have tried to add an updated leap-second file to the configuration and restart the service, but no luck, offsets is always the same (-1 second).

Comment: Of course this server should be updated, but by now there is no time for it. The plan is try to fix this problem now and buy hardware for a new server in 2021.

Comment: What offset?  the leap sec should not affect it--see https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/leap.html

Comment: re-reading this, I think it could be an incorrectly hard code leap second offset;  check out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64622764/number-of-seconds-between-two-dates-including-leap-seconds