# Number of seconds between two dates including leap seconds

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I'm fiddling around with time representation in C++.

I would like to have a strictly monotonic representation of time, that handles leap seconds well. The `utc_clock` in C++20 should be able to do that, and since my compiler doesn't support this version yet, I'm using [HowardHinnant/date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

To understand the library better I have started making small test cases, but got stuck on one.
I take two dates, before and after insertion of a leap second and check that duration between those two dates actually has the extra second.

This is the test case:

```
TEST(DateTime, TimeLeap)
{
  using namespace std::chrono;
  using namespace date;

  // Two dates with a leap second in between
  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second
  auto t1 = clock_cast<utc_clock>(static_cast<sys_days>(2016_y/December/31));
  auto t2 = clock_cast<utc_clock>(static_cast<sys_days>(2017_y/January/1));

  EXPECT_EQ(duration_cast<seconds>(t2 - t1).count(), 24 * 3600 + 1);
}
```

but it fails for me:

```
common/tests/datetime.cpp:39: Failure
      Expected: duration_cast<seconds>(t2 - t1).count()
      Which is: 86400
To be equal to: 24 * 3600 + 1
      Which is: 86401
```

It seems that the conversion between `sys_clock` and `utc_clock` doesn't add the leap second.

Suspecting that the problem is the resolution of `sys_days`, I've also tried doing a `time_point_cast<seconds>(...)` before the `clock_cast<utc_clock>`, but the result didn't change.
I've also tried using 2017-01-02 as the second date, in case there was an issue with distinction between 2016-12-31 23:59:60 and 2017-01-01 00:00 -- the leap second also didn't appear there.

Comment: Works fine here. How have you configured your installation of HowardHinnant/date?

Comment: I strongly suspect that for you `get_tzdb().leap_seconds.size() == 0`.  It should be 27.  This means that you're depending on your OS to supply leap second information (`USE_OS_TZDB=1`) and it is failing to do so.  Although there were some recent patches to tz.cpp in this regard:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/commit/ba99134b8a7c4a6e7d28d738a0234a85dc6bd827

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thank you, that's it! Could you please turn this into an answer so I can mark this as solved? And thanks for the awesome library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're using the OS supplied timezone database (`USE_OS_TZDB=1`), and that the leapseconds aren't being read.  This can be confirmed with:

```
cout << get_tzdb().leap_seconds.size() << '\n';
```

This should output 27 (currently), but for you I imagine it is outputting 0.  This means leapsecond data is missing.

With a recent (2020-09-11) commit:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/commit/ba99134b8a7c4a6e7d28d738a0234a85dc6bd827, the leapsecond data is read from either one of these files:

```
zoneinfo/leapseconds
zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list
```

Both of these files are IANA-supplied, but have slightly different formats.  Either file will do as they have duplicate information in them.  tz.cpp will search for both.  If your platform doesn't ship either one of these files, you can download it from [the IANA data download](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) and copy it into place manually.

Comment: The problem was that leap seconds were not loaded from my system tzdata. The commit you mentioned fixed the problem perfectly.